# Realign color container down and to the right from an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Image with color container directly underneath it

[image]

I have an image contained in some bootstrap classes and the custom class `round-img-wrapper`.  I am trying to realign the container to be ~`1em` down and ~`1em` to the right for the image I have attached here.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

```css
.round-img-wrapper {
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: rgba(71, 149, 224, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-lg-5" data-aos="fade-right">
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10 my-3 mx-3 py-4 px-4">
          <div class="round-img-wrapper">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBepG.png" class="rounded" alt=""><br><br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is your intended result? can you share an image?

Comment: `<br><br>` Don't do this. Use CSS if it's really needed

Comment: What is the issue with breaks?  

To the comment above, my intended result is this image to have the blue background but it would be a bit further up (still below the image) and to the right the image.  I guess I could probably define a border on the image itself, but I'd only want it on the bottom and right.